# Create a test web application replay to test and also to warm up a server

Tags: selenium, jmeter, katalon-studio

I would like to record a step through of a web application, and then replay this for testing. However it would be brilliant if this could be replayed say on a VM every so often to emulate a user to warm up a server.

JMeter, Katalon and Selenium have come up.

EDIT:

I have been playing with Katalon Studio and I'm very impressed with it in recording tests and replaying in a browser. This seems more about functional testing, ie do all the pages work. JMeter is about Load Testing. So different tools. However being able to export JMeter (JMX) files from Katalon would be fab, but I haven't heard it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMeter can/is used also for functional testing and have [selenium integration](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/selenium-vs-jmeter-which-one-should-you-choose-and-when)

> **Can JMeter and Selenium collaborate?**
>
> Yes. There are various situations where both tools can sync on the same testing application.

You can follow JMeter's [recording steps](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) to compare with katalon recording

Comment: Thanks for this. 2 questions, 1) Is it possible to export a Katalon Studio Script to JMeter? 2) What I like about Katalon is the Visual Screen Replay using different browsers. Is this possible with JMeter? I do like JMeter, but I do not want to record in Katalon and JMeter, especially when the app gets upgraded. I only want to keep one set of scripts up to date.

Comment: Any thoughts on how one could run a JMeter script from Azure, possibly via WebJobs as a warmup routine?

Comment: @SamJolly see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/load-test/get-started-jmeter-test?view=vsts

Comment: Thank for this.. Yes I have seen this article, but I could not see how one could schedule a test run through, say each morning at 6am, to warmup the servers.

Comment: Here's a how to schedule a load test https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2015/11/23/scheduling-load-test-execution/

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with Katalon Studio.

Here's what I do to warm-up the servers:

- I wrote a simple script (login with username and password, wait for web elements to load, logout),
- It is repeated on various servers,
- I put this Test Case in a Test Suite (because I can run test suites from command line),
- Generate a [console command](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/console-mode-execution.html),
- Use windows scheduler to run the test suite daily early in the morning, before users start working.

Comment: Thank you for this, really useful. How would you see this scheduled running of a script working in Azure?

Comment: Sorry, don't know about Azure.

Comment: I think it may be Azure Webjobs which can run an exe, cmd or ps file. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs

Comment: Maybe try creating a batch file that you could run on Azure. Not sure about the user roles, privileges, options, etc. when it comes to Azure.

Comment: I found your answer very helpful and Katalon has been a great find, however I think JMeter may be a better warm up solution for me, and user7294900 has provided Azure instructions. Thank you.